# Firing child method from parent vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, rendering

I am trying to represent a list of components defined in an array.

I need to fire child component method from parent.

I know that ref can be used to achieve this purpose, but my component is being rendering dynamically and I don't know how to encode that expression.

Im try this (code segment to explain the idea):

```
const childPaciente = ref()
.
.
onMounted:() => {
    childPaciente.value.submit()
}
```

The goal is that when the next button is clicked:

```
<button v-if="formPosition < patientProcess.length - 1" >
              Next            
</button>
```

the method of the child component fires:

```
methods: {
    submit() {
      //do something
}
```

This is my component array definition:

```
    import PacNew from '@/components/emp/global/PacNew.vue'
    import Step2 from '@/components/emp/global/Step2.vue'
    import Step3 from '@/components/emp/global/Step3.vue'
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    
    const childPaciente = ref()
    
    
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          formPosition: 0,
          animation: 'animate-in',
          datosPaciente:[],
          patientProcess: [
// NEW DEFINITION
      patientProcess: [
        { step: 1, visible: true, title: 'Subsection1', component: PacienteNuevo, comp:PacienteNuevo },
        { step: 2, visible: false, title: 'Subsection2', component: Step2, comp:Step2  },
        { step: 3, visible: false, title: 'Subsection3', component: Step3, comp:'' },
      ]        
}
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.$refs.comp)
      },
      components: {
        PacNew,
        Step2,
        Step3
      },
```

This is my code to render the components array:

```
 <section :class="animation">
              <h2>{{ patientProcess[formPosition].title }}</h2>
    
              <div>
                <div v-for="(tab, index) in patientProcess" :key="'component' + index">
                  <component v-if="patientProcess[index].visible" v-bind:is="tab.component" ref="comp">
                  </component>
                </div>
    
                <vs-tab v-for="(tab, index) in patientProcess" :label="tab.title" :key="index">
                  <component v-bind:is="tab.component">
                  </component>
                </vs-tab>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button v-if="formPosition < patientProcess.length - 1" >
                  Next
                </button>
                <button v-if="formPosition === patientProcess.length - 1">
                  Enter
                </button>
                <button v-if="formPosition < patientProcess.length && formPosition > 0" @click="prevStep">
                  Previous
                </button>
              </div>
    </section>
```

how can i achieve this.

Regards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ref the way you are is more akin to using refs with Vue 3's [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html) and `<script setup>` tag, rather than Vue 2's Options API.

With the Options API you just need to add the `ref` property to the component in your template, then you can access it in your methods with `this.$refs`. This is documented in the Vue 2 docs under [Accessing Child Component Instances & Child Elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

When the same ref is attached to multiple elements like with `v-for`, the `this.$refs` will hold an array of all elements with that same ref.

```html
<div v-for="(tab, index) in patientProcess">
  <component v-bind:is="tab.component" ref="comp">
</div>
```

Again you've mixed up Vue 3 Composition API and Options API when it comes to calling the mounted hook.  It's `onMounted:() => {}` with Composition API, `mounted() {}` with Options API

```js
// correct way to call mounted hook in Vue 2
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$refs.comp) // logs "[VueComponent, VueComponent, VueComponent]"
}
```

You can then search the array to find the specific component needed and call the desired method, or reference the exact index needed:

```
this.$refs.comp[0].submit()
```