# Using v-model to bind user input to state in the Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have this store:

```js
//store.js

import modulePaciente from './paciente/modulePaciente'
export default new Vuex.Store({
    getters,
    mutations,
    state,
    actions,
    modules: {
        paciente: modulePaciente
    },
})
```

And ... have this module where I'm trying to use vuex-map-fields

```js
//modulePaciente.js

import { getField,updateField } from "vuex-map-fields";

const state ={
    PacienteData: {
        name: '',
        code: '',
        lastname: '',
    }
}

const mutations ={
    updateField
}

const getters ={
    getField
}

const actions ={...}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    getters,
    actions
}
```

Finally, I have this component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="name">
    <input v-model="code">
    <input v-model="lastname">
        </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { mapFields } from "vuex-map-fields";

export default {
  name: "DatosGeneralesPaciente",
  data: () => ({}),
  computed: {
    ...mapFields("paciente", ["name", "code", "lastname"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

My problem is that nothing happen when I write in the input model field, when I move to the next input model field the value in the previous input is cleared:

[image]

I need to map my store to the v-model component. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've nested your state fields inside `PacienteData` you must follow the [documentation on nested properties](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields#nested-properties).

The `mapFields` value should be:

```js
...mapFields("paciente", [
  "PacienteData.name",
  "PacienteData.code",
  "PacienteData.lastname",
]),
```

Here is a working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-leaf-hbrymh?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: It is possible to use the mapFields logic directly in the component, this is because I need to use the component logic in a multi-step form and I don't want to use mapFields in every view that uses it.  Maybe do you remember this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75595688/firing-child-method-from-parent-vue-2  in that you helped me, the component will be rendered together with different steps, for this reason, I need make  the update of the store in the component